# How to parse a string of a kubectl cmd output in a shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, kubectl

`kubectl get nodes -o name` gives me the output

```
node/k8s-control.anything
node/k8s-worker1.anything
```

I need to get only

```
control
worker1
```

as output and want to iterate through these elements

```
for elm in $(kubectl get nodes -o name); do echo "$elm" >> file.txt; done
```

So the question is how to get the string between *node/k8s-* and *.anything* and iterate these in the for loop.

Comment: Have you read any basic tutorial on shell scripting?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk Shell scripting is quite new for me. I came up with the for loop and I get the correct kubectl cmd. But I'm stucked in the "link" by parsing the result. I know it is basic shell scripting stuff, but I got stucked for this

Comment: The tags "bash" and "shell" are mutually exclusive, as explained in their descriptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can for example use `cut` twice, first to get a part after `-` and
then to get a part before `.`:

```
for elm in $(kubectl get nodes -o name | cut -d- -f2 | cut -d. -f1); do echo "$elm" >> file.txt; done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grep` with `-oP` filter to extract the desired substring. Later, you can use `>` operator to redirect to the `file.txt`.

```
kubectl get nodes -o name|grep -oP 'node.*?-\K[^.]+'
control
worker1
```

Answer (score 0):

With `awk`

```
kubectl get nodes -o name | awk -F'[.-]' '{print $2}' > file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option might be bash parameter expansion:

```
while read -r line ; do line="${line#*-}"; line="${line%.*}";  printf "%s\n" "$line" ; done < <(kubectl get nodes -o name)
```